# How to do Sentiment analysis on tweets using LSTM without labeled data

Tags: twitter, analytics, lstm, sentiment-analysis

How to do sentiment analysis using LSTM in the tweets, without having labeled column of the tweet sentiment. What is the best approach to get good accuracy in sentiment on unlabeled data?

Answer (score 1):

If i'm understanding this correctly, you can't.. You need to train your NN and the way to do this in the most efficient manner is to have a dataset define the columns you require or that are of importance( in this case it would be sentiment label & sentiment text) You would then proceed to tokenize and group then proceed to adjust your NN. Sentiment analysis can be a tricky one so I hope you have access to a great GPU and knowledge of adjusting hyperparameters and symptoms of underfitting + overfitting, loss etc. After which you would load you, model, then predict which would generate a tuple adding up to one [0.6, 0.40] the first col being neg following pos. I would recommend reading "Deep Learning" by Bengio & Hinton in conjuntion with following popular channels that give you hands on.